# Traffic Redirection for transparent proxy

Tags: networking, router, proxy, redirection

My current network infrastructure (specifically the Archer D2 shown below) doesn't support redirecting of traffic, I am looking for some device or software that will allow me to redirect all traffic leaving the network on port 80 to the transparent proxy on the Raspberry Pi. The Archer D2 won't run any open source firmware I can find and my absolute budget is £100/$150. This is a plan of the network in its current configuration:

[image: Network plan]

*Microswitch should read Microfilter*

The pale dashed lines at the very bottom of the image are WiFi connections.

I am not wanting specific recommendations I am looking for the type of device I need to find etc.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution turned out to be as simple *and cheap* as changing the Default Gateway handed out by the DHCP server to the IP of the Raspberry Pi.

Then configuring the Pi's IPTables with the following options

```
sudo iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 21 -j REDIRECT --to-port 3128
sudo iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-port 3128
sudo iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 443 -j REDIRECT --to-port 3130
```